# hex to bin file conversion in bash

Tags: linux, bash, hex, bin, dd

This question has already been asked in many different forms. I need to convert a file that looks like this

```
41 20 42 20 43 20 44
```

to this

```
A B C D
```

This is just an example, but files WILL certainly contain non-printable characters.
I wrote a simple piece of code in `C` that does this, but I'm curious can it be done with some of the basic tools that are available on most `Linux` distributions, such as `dd` or `tr`, or maybe some clever bash script?

Comment: Perl can do it; so can Python, ...  AFAIK, there isn't a standard tool that just does the job.

Comment: The standard tool for this is `xxd`.  By default it expects the same format it spits out, including byte offsets, but with the right options it accepts raw hex digits.

Comment: `echo '41 20 42 20 43 20 44' | xxd -ps -g1 -r` and `xxd` also accepts files as input.

Comment: tx, I have `xxd` on all my distros, and it's simple to use!

Answer (score 1):

For the sample input this works (in bash at least). Whether it will work for all input I'm not sure but I expect it probably will.

```
printf %b $(printf '\\x%s ' $(< infile)); echo
```